# Unbalanced brackets error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command byt it's saying `Unbalanced brackets` in the output.

Can somebody help me fixing it

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"NeverWinter Cosmetic's Trader",CustomNameVisible:1,Profession:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Chest}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Slime}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Lavaslime}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Villager}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Present2}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Creeper}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Spider}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_CaveSpider}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Blaze}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Endermite}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_TNT}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Ghast}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3}        ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_EnderDragon}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3}        ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Enderman}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Zombie}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Apple}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Cake}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Melon}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Pumpkin}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3}        ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_PigZombie}}},        {maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3}        ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:NeverWinterKing}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Ocelot}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Herobrine}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Present1}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"4cf7beb1-db9b-414d-914a-212f5346720d",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOGEzZmY5NTk4NTc2ZGI1ZjUxZjk0MTZmMjRiNTUyOGI3YzI2NjY2MDZjOTc3MGRjMTE0MThlY2NjYjdhYzFmIn19fQ=="}]}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"a00844e9-7799-47b7-80f7-37a4da562ccb",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDQ4OTYzNjAxMTUyMWYzM2NjNzRlYWFiM2RlYjg3NjRhZThlZDQ3ZTViNjRjMWUyYjZlOThiYmE3NmI0NDkifX19"}]}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"8146ebc2-97f8-40ad-a9f4-f56331cd1973",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvODA3MmExNDVkYWJkOGM0NzQ3MWRlZTRkZjQ2NmQ5MTdjMjQ3ZGY1MjkwNGUzNDRlZWU3ZjVmMjY0NDU3ZjEifX19"}]}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"b2a1d690-c51d-4c5e-b5e3-4dde31e37c7a",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNTc0YWJmZmQyZjkwYTU5OTU4ZjJiZTI5YmM5YmY1NTllN2YzNzlmZTU1YThjZDE4ZWFlNWQ5MGE4MjZhYzQxIn19fQ=="}]}} {maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"e3d33b66-185b-4aec-a41a-c1360dd383a0",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvN2Y0YjhjOWYzMzc4NjkxNTllZDMxYTcxYmQ1MDNiNzI1YjJlZTI2NGE2ZWIxMWU1OGU2NTdlMWE4YTk5YyJ9fX0="}]}}{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:"{SkullOwner:"b63f915d-b9a5-4982-b131-2608ef51ccb5",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMmQyOTgzOGM1ZWZhMzE0NDY5NTRhM2YzZGViNDczNTgyZDAyZmNhNjM5MWQyMzJjZWJkMzI5YjM4ZWVmZWEifX19"}]}}{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:"{SkullOwner:"05811e6c-c8f3-4e83-b952-e70ecf1a7a74",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvYTQzMzE4NTI4OWU2NzkzOWY0NDAzNDhkMTk2YzU0MThiZjNlOTYyNDU2Nzc2OGJmYTZlZmE4NGI0ZmViNWEifX19"}]}}{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:"{SkullOwner:"8eb02265-571d-4b9b-8b03-1dae7fb85bab",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWU5OTg0NTcxNTU5MmJiZGUyNzQ4NzllMjcyODE1MTM1ZTZlODE0Y2Y0NDI4NTY3N2M2YzliMDc1Y2E0YmYyIn19fQ=="}]}}{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:"{SkullOwner:"5228d050-9c8f-417d-9809-8f283a3ae345",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMWY5MTg1MzRjM2U1YzI1ZDQxNjVjZTgxMjNiNzI2Yzc0ZmY3MzRjMWQ1MmIzNjI0NzlkZGE3OTI1MCJ9fX0="}}}]}},Age:0,Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:,Damage:0,Count:1}],DropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1}
```

The letters are also the heads.

Comment: Unbalanced brackets means that somewhere you've opened a bracket, but not closed it, or vice versa. You're on your own to figure out where that is, though

Comment: do you know whats the problem I would like the working command please

Comment: Like @SaintWacko said, unbalanced brackets mean that one of your opening brackets isn't closed, or one of your closing brackets isn't opened. That's the problem. Look at it and find the one without a match.

Comment: You have loads of Extra opening brackets, I made a counter [here](https://ideone.com/TPoeqR). You can see that the output is "Opening bracket count: 157. Closing bracket count: 139".

Comment: it didn't work?

Comment: We're not going to do your fixing job for you. That's not what this site is for. We've gone above and beyond to tell you what the problem is and how to fix it, even though your question is off topic. Now it's up to you what you do with that information.

Comment: ok I don't know how to find the closing or the opening and I cant figure out whats wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, I found it. It's around `MHF_Present1`, there's a closing bracket missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is the unbalanced brackets. Every time you open a bracket, with `[` or `{`, you need to close it later on, with `]` or `}`; a lot of this seems as though you've just guessed at how many brackets will be needed.

You've also missed out commas between tags in a lot of places:

> 9fQ=="}]}} {maxUses:999999

And missed out actually putting something in the id tag again:

> Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:,Damage:0,Count:1}],

Here's the fixed command:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"NeverWinter Cosmetic's Trader",CustomNameVisible:1,Profession:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Chest}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Slime}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Lavaslime}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Villager}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Present2}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Creeper}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Spider}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_CaveSpider}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Blaze}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Endermite}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_TNT}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Ghast}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3} ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_EnderDragon}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3} ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Enderman}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Zombie}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Apple}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Cake}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Melon}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Pumpkin}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3} ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_PigZombie}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3} ,sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:NeverWinterKing}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Ocelot}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Damage:0,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Herobrine}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Present1}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"4cf7beb1-db9b-414d-914a-212f5346720d",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOGEzZmY5NTk4NTc2ZGI1ZjUxZjk0MTZmMjRiNTUyOGI3YzI2NjY2MDZjOTc3MGRjMTE0MThlY2NjYjdhYzFmIn19fQ=="}]}}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"a00844e9-7799-47b7-80f7-37a4da562ccb",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDQ4OTYzNjAxMTUyMWYzM2NjNzRlYWFiM2RlYjg3NjRhZThlZDQ3ZTViNjRjMWUyYjZlOThiYmE3NmI0NDkifX19"}]}}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"8146ebc2-97f8-40ad-a9f4-f56331cd1973",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvODA3MmExNDVkYWJkOGM0NzQ3MWRlZTRkZjQ2NmQ5MTdjMjQ3ZGY1MjkwNGUzNDRlZWU3ZjVmMjY0NDU3ZjEifX19"}]}}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"b2a1d690-c51d-4c5e-b5e3-4dde31e37c7a",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNTc0YWJmZmQyZjkwYTU5OTU4ZjJiZTI5YmM5YmY1NTllN2YzNzlmZTU1YThjZDE4ZWFlNWQ5MGE4MjZhYzQxIn19fQ=="}]}}}},{maxUses:999999,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"e3d33b66-185b-4aec-a41a-c1360dd383a0",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvN2Y0YjhjOWYzMzc4NjkxNTllZDMxYTcxYmQ1MDNiNzI1YjJlZTI2NGE2ZWIxMWU1OGU2NTdlMWE4YTk5YyJ9fX0="}]}}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"b63f915d-b9a5-4982-b131-2608ef51ccb5",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMmQyOTgzOGM1ZWZhMzE0NDY5NTRhM2YzZGViNDczNTgyZDAyZmNhNjM5MWQyMzJjZWJkMzI5YjM4ZWVmZWEifX19"}]}}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"05811e6c-c8f3-4e83-b952-e70ecf1a7a74",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvYTQzMzE4NTI4OWU2NzkzOWY0NDAzNDhkMTk2YzU0MThiZjNlOTYyNDU2Nzc2OGJmYTZlZmE4NGI0ZmViNWEifX19"}]}}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"8eb02265-571d-4b9b-8b03-1dae7fb85bab",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWU5OTg0NTcxNTU5MmJiZGUyNzQ4NzllMjcyODE1MTM1ZTZlODE0Y2Y0NDI4NTY3N2M2YzliMDc1Y2E0YmYyIn19fQ=="}]}}}},{maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{SkullOwner:"5228d050-9c8f-417d-9809-8f283a3ae345",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMWY5MTg1MzRjM2U1YzI1ZDQxNjVjZTgxMjNiNzI2Yzc0ZmY3MzRjMWQ1MmIzNjI0NzlkZGE3OTI1MCJ9fX0="}]}}}}]},Age:0,Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{}],DropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1}
```

In the future, use a generator/filter for these types of commands, or write it bit-by-bit and test it as you go along, otherwise you end up with a giant unworkable command like this with errors somewhere in it.

Answer (score -1):

More `{` than `}` in command add `}` 18 times somewhere in command. Where? I don't know.

Open a text editor paste the command
Put an go to the next line for each section of the command and try figuring it out.

If you wrote all that code these last 18 brackets won't be a problem

Comment: Well... Why don't you tell where and fix the command?